# Render User field in Display Suite custom fields

Tags: entities, tokens, display-suite

I am trying to use display suite custom field to show a user avatar field (custom field).  In my DS tokens, the field is available as `[comment:author:field_user_avatar]`.  But the field/image does not show.  I have even tried the `...avatar:file]` and `..avatar:url]`.  But it just renders nothing.  However, the `[comment:author:field_your_name]` does work.

I have also tried the $entity type, but that field does not seem to be there.

Is there any other way to display an author user(image) field?